# How do I find all CR+LF's in a string?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to replace all carrage returns with a `<br/>` tag in C#.  I thought this would take care of everything:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
sb.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, @"<br/>");
```

But apparently not.  It doesn't seem to catch `CR+LF`.

Comment: Have you verified that `s` contains `\r\n` and not simply `\n`?

Comment: `System.Environment.Newline` is going to depend on the executing environment. As ChaosPandion said, it is likely that you're actually just working with `\n`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That will work *if* `Environment.NewLine` is CR+LF, which it's likely to be on Windows. Of course it won't catch the situation where the string actually only contains line feeds, or only contains carriage returns. Perhaps you want:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s).Replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
                                       .Replace("\n", "<br/>")
                                       .Replace("\r", "<br/>");
```

(Note that there's no point in using a verbatim string literal for `"<br/>"` as there's no backslash in the string, and it's a single line.)

Comment: Why are you always 30 seconds faster than me :(

Comment: @JimSchubert - Must be mind-recognition software or something :)

Comment: @Adel, It's most likely the rule "There are two types of programmers: good programmers, and those that are not Jon Skeet." [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9138/152872)

Answer (score 3):

If you know for sure you will replace \r\n why not just use string.replace?

```
s.replace("\r\n", "<br/>")
```

Answer (score 3):

By this code

```
input.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", "\r\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string ReplaceNewlines(string blockOfText, string replaceWith)
{
    return blockOfText.Replace("\r\n", replaceWith).Replace("\n", replaceWith).Replace("\r", replaceWith);
}
```